# Both question go to the same link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, exact-duplicates

I was searching for a question I read last week because want to share with my brother. The problem is when you [search the term "chess"](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?q=chess) the question I want appear on the first position (because is the most recent), but the link take me to the same question as the one on second position.

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, looks like is fixed now. I try to looks for the same question using other keywords in case where a bug regarding the position where appear and found the right question. Went back to the original tab where I found the error and the link is working now.

Comment: Now I can see the question I was looking for, realize was marked duplicated as the second one. So maybe there was a bug of some kind there.

Comment: Were you logged in when you were redirected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that you just created your account - probably when you came to ask this meta question.

This isn't a bug, it's [status-bydesign](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

From the [Duplicates FAQ on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled):

> Furthermore, if the question is unanswered, and there is only one target, then anonymous visitors are automatically redirected to the duplicate.

If you're logged in, you get the actual question you click on, which is why it "works" now... you created an account here.

This was [implemented back in 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr).

Comment: You are right. I'm always lurking around but never press the create button because never had any additional comment until now. (Yes I'm lazy like that:$)